# Replacing closing tag with space in xsl

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm having trouble trying to convert a heavily nested xml file to text. The output I really want is simply the text content of certain nodes and their children (in this case node 'div' of type 'secondBit' and 'thirdBit'). Unfortunately there are some internal tags (span class="bold") which need to be removed and the closing tag replaced by a space. Here's the input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myxml>
<content>
<p class="heading">Omit this please</p>
  <div type="firstBit">
    <div class="extended"><span class="italic">this as well</span>
    </div>
    <meta name="factor"/>
  </div>
  <div type="secondBit">
    <p>
      <meta name="first" id="9"/>Some text in here.</p>
  </div>
  <div type="thirdBit">
    <div class="internal" >
      <div class="intro">
        <p class="varied">And then a <span class="bold">Button</span>can be pushed <span class="bold">without</span>any trouble</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</content>
</myxml>
```

Here's the xsl I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"
    omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@type= ('secondBit', 'thirdBit')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However this gives me the output:

> Some text in here.And then a Buttoncan be pushed withoutany trouble

whereas I would like the output (note the spaces):

> Some text in here.And then a Button can be pushed without any trouble

I know I probably have to somehow introduce the following xsl snippet, but I'm not sure how:

```
<xsl:template match="span[@class='bold']">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

If this isn't the place to ask these questions, I do apologise for wasting peoples time.

Otherwise thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="*[not(.//div[@type= ('secondBit', 'thirdBit')])]"/>

<xsl:template match="*[.//div[@type= ('secondBit', 'thirdBit')]] |
                     div[@type= ('secondBit', 'thirdBit')] |
                     div[@type= ('secondBit', 'thirdBit')]//*" priority="5">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@type= ('secondBit', 'thirdBit')]//span[@class='bold']" priority="10">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply that with Saxon 9.4 HE to your input sample I get the result `Some text in here.And then a Button can be pushed without any trouble`.

Comment: Cheers Martin, you're a life-saver :)